# Excel question about counting the number of unique IDS when the value in a column matches the value in another column

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula to count the number of unique IDS when the value in a column matches the value in another column.

[Column A - Year | Column B - Number of Unique Firms | Column D - Firm ID Number | Column E - Year 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4uJ.png)

For B2 I want a formula that says, check column D for the number of unique firms that had a transaction in the year (Year 2 column) that matches the value in A2.  Basically give a count of all the firms that had a transaction in 2013.

I am trying to generate the values that are highlighted in the above picture in yellow.
In the actual data, Columns D and E are in a separate spreadsheet and there are over 150 thousand rows.

Answer (score 1):

Formula solution without helper column

In `B2`, enter formula :

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E$2:E$15=A2)/(COUNTIFS(D$2:D$15,D$2:D$15,E$2:E$15,E$2:E$15)))
```

[image]

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.  Thank you!!! This is exactly what I was looking for and will save me hours of work!  On Tuesday, I was playing around with sumproduct and 1/countifs (after lots of Googling online), but I was not getting the right answers.  Your code is perfect!!! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your limitations are, e.g. VBA, Helper Columns, etc. But here's a solution using helper columns.

You need 3 formulas:

1. Find the UNIQUE Firm IDs: G4 =UNIQUE(D3:D16)
2. Count the entries by year for each unique Firm ID:
   H3 =COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$16,$G3,$E$3:$E$16,H$1)
3. Tally the entries for each year: B3 =COUNTIF(OFFSET(H$3:H$5,0,ROW()-3),"<>"&0)

You need to setup your helper columns as shown here:
[image]

Place formula 1 in G4 after adjusting the references, which I'd highly recommend you to change to dynamic range names. There is no need to do anything further with this formula!

Next, place formula 2 in H3 and then fill down and across, again using dynamic range names.

Lastly place formula 3 in B3 and fill down. Once again using dynamic range names.

The result:
[image]
HTH

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.  While the helper column is a great idea, it would take a long time give the size of my data.  Thank you for the help!